# REST api calling in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi im learning about REST API and used this link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/588909/ASP-NET-WEB-API-Basics-MVC-4 . And i have developed a small API . Following is my controller

```
 public class FileController : ApiController
    {

 [HttpGet]
    public List<files> get()
    {
        DBQuery k = new DBQuery();
        List<files> listOfFiles = k.GetAll();
        return listOfFiles;

    }



    [HttpPost]
    public int  get(int v)
    {
        return (v);

    }
```

having two methods namely **get** and **upload** and by using the below url i can access the **get** method

```
http://localhost:53081/api/File
```

but when i give  `http://localhost:53081/api/File/1` this i can access **upload** method . Still im getting the **get** methods result

what went wrong in my code . Kindly help me . im new to this

**update**

if i cal the method **upload** im still getting the **get** methods result on my screen

what went wrong

**Images**

[image]

and for this  `http://localhost:53081/api/File/1` also im getting **404 error** and i have used REST Client plugin to post the url

Comment: Can you present the full code example (it is incomplete)? Can you specify a little more what you want to do?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You're omitting `upload` from the URL... `http://localhost:53081/api/File/upload/1`

Comment: Do you want to access `http://localhost:53081/api/File/1/upload`? Because, in my opinion, you cannot.

Comment: No i want to access upload . how can i access it

Comment: `POST` to `http://localhost:53081/api/file/upload`

Comment: @meilke   i have updated some images this will be helpful

Comment: Its all about the HTTP verb of your request. If you keep doing `GET` requests, the requests will keep getting routed to methods that have a name starting with `Get`.

Comment: You need to have both methods there using the HttpGet attribute. They are both get methods. If you call the second one like this, http://localhost:53081/api/File/1. It will return 1, that is correct for the code you have shown us.

Comment: By convention the API should have the method using the same Http verb (Get, Post). Your methods on the code, are both Get methods, so you tyoe the URI into the browser and get a result. For a Post verb you need to post something, so submitting a form or using a Rest client like fiddler (as in my answer) to produce a Post request is what you need to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be best to rename your methods like so

```
[HttpGet]
public List<File> Get()
{
    return myFileClass.MyMethodThatReturnsAListOfFiles;
}

[HttpGet]
public File Get(int id)
{
    return myFileClass.MyMethodThatReturnsASpecificFile(id);
}
```

The upload method you have is a bit confusing as it should really take in a File object and be restricted to only use the HttpPost method. Youd need to use a rest client (plugin for chrome, or use Fiddler) to get this to work, but stick with the pattern above and you'll be ok.

My guess at a method to replace your upload method is

```
[HttpPost]
public File Post(File uploadedFile)
{
   return myFileClass.MyMethodThatSavesAFileAndReturnsItWithANewId(uploadedFile);
}
```

Comment: why we need to use (int id) variable name as "id" if i give something else it is not working why

Comment: If you look in your WebApi.config in the App_Start folder of your api site you will see the routeTemplate is set to api/{controller}/{id}. This is the default, if you want your request to route through to a method with a different param name you need to add it. Convention is that you have a uri like api/Controller/MyParamName/{myParamName} for method Get(int myParamName);